How clean is seafood from Hong Kong local waters?
I want to eat seafood caught in HK waters. To my disbelief, every expat that I met in Hong Kong raised their eyebrows when I asked for restaurant recommendations for local HK seafood. They do not feel comfortable with Hong Kong water, they said.
What's the catch - pun intended - with HK waters, and seafood caught near HK?
Are these quotations telling the truth?

Given the same level of freshness, the flower crab caught in Hong Kong’s waters is especially flavourful with bouncy flesh.


If you're a seafood lover, Hong Kong is the place to be. With its coastal location, the city is home to a vast array of seafood restaurants offering the freshest catches of the day.


This is very similar to your earlier question

@traveller no. this one asks about cleanliness. the other asks about possible false marketing.

First of all define "clean".
